# Multiple Slideshows on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm really struggling by adding multiple slideshows one a single page.
One works really fine, but as soon as I add the second one it crashes.

I think the problem is in the Javascript, but I really don't have a clou, what I could do about it. Tried already a lot…

If anybody has some ideas, I would really appreciate it.
Thank you already for your support!!

This is how the **HTML** looks:

```
 <!-- slideshow 1 -->

<div class="slidercontainer">  
    <div class="showSlide fade">  
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" />   
    </div>  
    <div class="showSlide fade">  
        <img src="images/img2.jpg"/>  
    </div>  
    <div class="showSlide fade">  
        <img src="images/img3.jpg"/>   
    </div>  
    <!-- Navigation arrows -->  
    <a class="left" onclick="nextSlide(-1)">LEFT</a>  
    <a class="right" onclick="nextSlide(1)">RIGHT</a>  
</div>  

<p> text between slideshow </p>

<!-- slideshow 2 -->

<div class="slidercontainer">  
    <div class="showSlide fade">  
        <img src="images/img1.jpg" />   
    </div>  
    <div class="showSlide fade">  
        <img src="images/img2.jpg"/>  
    </div>  
    <div class="showSlide fade">  
        <img src="images/img3.jpg"/>   
    </div>  
    <!-- Navigation arrows -->  
    <a class="left" onclick="nextSlide(-1)">LEFT</a>  
    <a class="right" onclick="nextSlide(1)">RIGHT</a>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {  
margin: 0;  
background: #e6e6e6;  
    }  
    .showSlide {  
        display: none  
    }  
        .showSlide img {  
            width: 100%;  
        }  
    .slidercontainer {  
        max-width: 65vw;  
        position: relative;   
        background: red;
    }  
    .left, .right {  
        cursor: pointer;  
        position: absolute;  
        top: 0;
        height: 100%;  
        width: 50%;  
        color: white;  
        font-weight: bold;  
        font-size: 18px;  
        transition: 0.6s ease;  
        border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;  
    }  
    .right {  
        right: 0;  
        border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;  
    }  
        .left:hover, .right:hover {  
            background-color: rgba(115, 115, 115, 0.8);  
        }  

    .active {  
        background-color: #717171;  
    }  
    /* Fading animation */  
    .fade {  
        -webkit-animation-name: fade;  
        -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;  
        animation-name: fade;  
        animation-duration: 1.5s;  
    }  
    @-webkit-keyframes fade {  
        from {  
            opacity: .4  
        }  
        to {  
            opacity: 1  
        }  
    }  

    @keyframes fade {  
        from {  
            opacity: .4  
        }  
        to {  
            opacity: 1  
        }  
    }
```

**Javascript:**

```
var slide_index = 1;  
displaySlides(slide_index);  
function nextSlide(n) {  
displaySlides(slide_index += n);  
    }  

    function currentSlide(n) {  
        displaySlides(slide_index = n);  
    }  
    function displaySlides(n) {  
        var i;  
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("showSlide");  
        if (n > slides.length) { slide_index = 1 }  
        if (n < 1) { slide_index = slides.length }  
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {  
            slides[i].style.display = "none";  
        }  
        slides[slide_index - 1].style.display = "block";  
    }
```

Comment: It seems like the JavaScript will only handle one gallery at a time. What is it you are after? A suggestion on how to make the gallery more flexible so it could support more than one instance in a page?

Comment: @Narxx Yes exactly, I would love to have multiply slideshows working underneath each other on one single page...

Answer (score 2):

Your current problem is that your gallery assumes all elements with class name `showSlide` belongs to the gallery, where as this is not what you are after.

Instead of selecting the elements with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("showSlide");
```

you will need to identify which gallery is to be triggered.
Try sending the gallery id to the `nextSlide()` function. This way you'll be able to accurately select the slides of the right gallery.

```
<a class="left" onclick="nextSlide(-1, 'gallery1')">LEFT</a>
```

and give each gallery container that identifier:

```
<div class="slidercontainer" id="gallery1">
    ...
</div>
```

This way, in your `nextSlide` function, you'll get that id and pass it to `displaySlides` like so

```
function nextSlide(n, gallery) {  
    displaySlides(slide_index += n, gallery);  
}
```

When initialising the galleries, you'll need to have a loop that will iterate over all the galleries dynamically

```
var galleries = document.querySelectorAll('.slidercontainer');
for (i = 0 ; i < galleries.length ; i++) {
    displaySlides(slide_index, galleries[i]);
}
```

and finally, select only the slides for the proper gallery

```
var slides = document.querySelector('#' + gallery + ' .showSlide');
```

Seems like it would work. I haven't tested it myself, and would probably implement this whole thing a bit different, but as for your question, this should be okay. If anything is unclear, or doesn't work, feel free do drop a comment and I'd take a look at it.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Everything sounds very clear and comprehensibly. But when I implement the Javascript, no images are shown. 

I don't know what I made wrong… 
Do I need to add something else?

Comment: Well, for instance, you have the call to init the gallery on the top of the JS file: `displaySlides(slide_index);` which should also be modified. I'll add a possible loop init in my answer.